# IIS Reverse proxy and URL Rewrite don't work

Tags: iis, rewrite, reverse-proxy

I did following steps:

1. Installed all neede features to IIS (URLRewrite 2.0, ARR, ...)
2. Created default MVC Web Application in VisualStudio
3. Added this web app as new site to iis (I can access it by `http://localhost`)
4. Opened URLRewrite for this site
5. Clicked `Add Rule(s)...`
6. Chose `Reverse Proxy`
7. Entered `google.com` as server where HTTP requests will be forwareded
8. Unchecked `Enable SSL Offloading`
9. Clicked `OK`

When I access `http://localhost` I still have my own webapp, not `google.com`. In my `web.config` I have:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://google.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Then I tried to add more usefull rule: rewriting `localhost/google/sth` to `google.com/search?q=sth`.
I changed `web.config`:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^google/(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://google.com/search?q={R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this to work? Im guessing even if you did, the solution is so illogical you possibly dont remember how it was achieved :D Im having the same issue and tearing my hair out...